# no method named `contains` found for struct `schema::users::columns::roles` in the current scope

Tags: arrays, postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I'm new to rust and trying to create a sample webapi. I'm using postgres and have a column named "roles" as a type of array. I want to use contains method from diesel::expression_methods::PgArrayExpressionMethods but having an error saying "no method named `contains` found for struct `schema::users::columns::roles` in the current scope"

schema.rs

```rust
table! {
    users (id) {
        id -> Uuid,
        username -> Varchar,
        email -> Varchar,
        password -> Varchar,
        first_name -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        last_name -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        active -> Bool,
        roles -> Nullable<Array<Text>>,
        created_at -> Timestamp,
        updated_at -> Timestamp,
    }
}
```

in the handler method:

```rust
users.filter(roles.contains(vec!["admin"])).get_results::<User>(&conn)
```

Answer (score 1):

And just as I was writing this question, I've found the problem. It doesn't work with *nullable* array columns. I've rerolled the migrations with a default empty array and now it works :)

new schema.rs

```rust
table! {
    users (id) {
        id -> Uuid,
        username -> Varchar,
        email -> Varchar,
        password -> Varchar,
        first_name -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        last_name -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        active -> Bool,
        roles -> Array<Text>,
        created_at -> Timestamp,
        updated_at -> Timestamp,
    }
}
```

new migrations/.../up.sql

```
.
.
  roles text [] not null default array[]::text[], 
.
.
```